# Is jQuery(document).ready() an asynchronous function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The problem behind my question in the title is this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    var height = jQuery( "#current-image" ).css( "height" ); // Retrieve height
    jQuery( '#prev' ).css( 'height', height + 'px' );        // Set element to that height
});
```

First I retrieve the height of the element "current-image". Then I want to set that height to another element, called "prev".

- The element "prev"'s default height is 200 px.
- The element "current-image"'s height is 350 px
- I want the element "prev"s height to be 350 px

Somehow the element "prev" keeps it original height 200px. When I put an alert(height); statement between the two lines of code the variable is indeed 350 but it never sets the height of the "prev" element. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong since this is such an simple bit of code..

Comment: Are you sure `height` is `350`, or is it `350px`?

Comment: It is a silly question, but just for curiosity, what happens when you do something like this: `jQuery( '#prev' ).css( 'height', jQuery( "#current-image" ).css( "height" ) + 'px' );` ?

Comment: It will work if you remove the "+'px'"

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but in case you're not aware: images may take time to load, at that point their height could be `0` (FF), `32px` (IE) or any other value depending on what amount of image has been loaded + how the browser chooses to render _partial_ images.

Comment: BoltClock: Yes the value of the variable height was actually 350px, not 350.

Removing the "px" as Capsule said solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

height should contain "350px" and not "350" because you're getting the CSS value for this element, not the computed height (without unit). So you don't need to add + 'px', because you'll obviously get "350pxpx" which is invvalid, hence the height not changing.

Comment: Indeed it did containt 350px so I added px 2 times which made it all buggy. Tnx for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height) instead. This way you don't have to deal with pixel units as the method assumes pixels:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var height = jQuery('#current-image').height();
    jQuery('#prev').height(height);
});
```

Comment: Will work if the size of #current-image is defined in the CSS (looks like it's the case now, but then I wonder why we are trying to get it in javascript since it's a fixed value ;-)), but will fail randomly if not, because when document is ready, images are not necessarly loaded and their heights could be reported as 0.